# subset data frame based on percentage

Tags: r, subset

i have a data frame that contains a data like this :

```
V1 V2 V3
1  2  0.34
1  3  0.31
1  4  0.12
1  5  0.12
```

the data frame is bigger but that's an example.

i want to take a subset of this data frame that has the lowest 20% of V3.

how this can be done ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `subset()` function is handy because (among other benefits) it allows you to avoid having to repeatedly mention the name of the data-frame:

```
subset(dataFrame, V3 <= quantile(V3, 0.2))
```

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani :  thnx for help , i will try it , but how should i make sure that it gaves the needed results ?
and will it give the lowest 20% of values of V3 :S
sorry for asking alot but i'm new to R

Comment: @smack: If you use my answer, you'll have an object 'ss' which you can check against the original dataframe 'dataFrame'. The following two quantities should be (roughly) the same: length(row.names(dataFrame))/5 and length(row.names(ss)).

Comment: @smack you can test it with an example data-frame where the `V3` column contains the sequence of integers `1:100`

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani :  i check it as you suggested , and it wil work , thanks :)

Comment: why not use dataframe[quantile(V3, 0.2)<=V3,3]?

Comment: @Manoel -- how can your syntax work? We need to qualify the `V3` inside the `[..]` with the name of the data-frame, like `dataFrame$V3`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, the correct code is: dataframe[V3<=quantile(V3, 0.2),]. V3<=quantile(V3, 0.2) returns a false/true for each row, right? So, just use [ operator to subsect these rows. The specification of column in my example is unimportant. Just use df = dataframe[V3<=quantile(V3, 0.2),]

Comment: @Manoel -- your code won't work: you are referring to  `V3` inside the `[..]`, so you will get an error saying "Object `V3` not found". The only way the code would work is if you already did `attach(dataFrame)`, so this approach requires two statements. Moreover you always have to be careful when doing `attach()` -- it makes it hard to keep track of which variables are visible and which variables are being masked, etc.

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani : in case i want to take the lowest 10 points of the error , how this can be done ??

Comment: @smack -- not sure what you mean by "lowest 10 pts of the error"...?

Comment: Not need to attach. Just use dataframe$V3. Or use with... In anycase, I just post another possibiliy and I prefer to use "[" than subset in this cases... But I guess is a question of taste...

Comment: @Manoel -- ok I see, I was taking your code literally. Of course it would work when you say `[dataFrame$V3 ... ]`, or you could do `with(dataFrame, dataFrame[ V3 <= quantile(V3,.2), ]`. Both of those approaches require mentioning the data-frame name *twice*, and I prefer `subset` because you only mention it once.

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani : sorry , i mean the lowest 10 points of V3

Comment: @smack: you can do `subset(dataFrame, rank(V3) <= 10 )`

Answer (score 4):

```
ss <- subset(dataFrame, subset=(dataFrame$V3 <= quantile(dataFrame$V3, 0.20)))
```

Comment: @smack: If you don't mind, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49000/given-two-practically-identical-useful-answers-which-answer-do-you-vote-for

Comment: @smack: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74557/what-if-2-answers-are-essentially-the-same (especially preference for the user who answered first)