# how to look at specific subset of a dataset

Tags: r, dataset, distribution

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
 foo     bar
 23      0
 72      1
 41      1
 32      2
 21      1
 21      1
```

I want to plot a qq plot and a histogram of the distribution of foo at bar equal to 1. How would I do that?

I know `plot` and `qqnorm` for qq plot. And I know `hist`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [subset data frame based on percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253837/subset-data-frame-based-on-percentage)

Comment: This is pretty basic R stuff. Have a look at [the manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html).

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of a question that only uses `subset` in the answers, imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply subset as the other suggested.

```
> subset(df, bar==1)
```

or in one line for the `hist` function

```
> hist(subset(df, bar==1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get all rows with bar==1. Following should work:

```
df1 = ddf[ddf$bar==1,]

df1
  foo bar
2  72   1
3  41   1
5  21   1
6  21   1

plot(df1$foo, df1$bar)
```