# Subset R dataframe based on proportion of total column value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe `df` as given below (sample for ease of asking):

```
ID       Sales
10001   214108 
10002   207858
10003    76548
10004    68361
10005    56456
```

I need to subset `df` such that the resulting rows will contain 90% of total Sales. I came across this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253837/subset-data-frame-based-on-percentage), but I am not getting the desired result. What I used was the following:

```
subset(df, Sales >= quantile(Sales,0.9))
```

What I get is the following:

```
     >ID  Sales
     <dbl>  <dbl>
  1 10001 214108
```

My current idea is to do it the following way:

1. Add a new column using: `df$Sales_pct = Sales/sum(Sales)`
2. Sort `df` in descending order of `Sales_pct` column values
3. Add another column with cumulative percentage and then subset rows that have the cumulative percentage value less than 0.9

But, I feel there should be a better approach for this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R base approach:

```
#1.Add a new column using: df$Sales_pct = Sales/sum(Sales)
df$Sales_pct <- with(df, Sales/sum(Sales))

#2.Sort df in descending order of Sales_pct column values
df <- df[order(df$Sales_pct, decreasing = TRUE), ]

#3.Add another column with cumulative percentage and then subset rows that have 
# the cumulative percentage value less than 0.9
df$Sales_cum <- cumsum(df$Sales_pct)
subset(df, Sales_cum < .90)

     ID  Sales Sales_pct Sales_cum
1 10001 214108 0.3434901 0.3434901
2 10002 207858 0.3334633 0.6769533
3 10003  76548 0.1228047 0.7997581
```

A `tidyverse` approach

```
df %>% mutate(Sales_pct = Sales/sum(Sales)) %>% 
  arrange(-Sales_pct) %>% 
  mutate(Sales_cum = cumsum(Sales_pct)) %>% 
  filter(Sales_cum <= 0.90)
```

Comment: The `tidyverse` approach works for me, so I am accepting the answer.